# Netsuite: Paying by check led to a credit card sale. This expected?

Tags: netsuite

I created a sales order in NS and marked the payment method as check. When I went to bill it, it created a credit card sale, even though there was no credit card on the transaction. Is this expected?

Comment: The transaction payment type was set to check and never changed: https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=957031&c=3514567&h=2fdd1ba959e1ce4d78ae

Comment: And then here's the credit card sale, with a check number filled in: https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=957032&c=3514567&h=ab8a2b60c08e7a205a38

Comment: I'm wondering if you can post the url of your second image. I'm guessing you've done some transaction re-naming in your account and that is just a normal Cash Sale record with a different name.

Comment: I think you are right...the url is: https://system.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/cashsale.nl?whence=&id=317537

Comment: Thanks all! All good information. I think the bottom line for us is that our sales order writers need to be cognizant of the fact it default fill in a credit card if there's one on file. Historically, we didn't have an online presence and so people only paid via one method. Now, customers are paying via multiple methods and so people need to watch which sales terms/payment methods are being selected for a given transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no transaction in NetSuite with name "credit card sale", it's an standard cash sale transaction. May be this record is renamed in your NetSuite account.

A customer may have a Credit Card saved in their record. When creating a sales order, under the billing tab the preferred Credit Card details will be auto-populated under the "Payment" subtab. When the user enters a Term under "Billing Information" section, the Payment Method field under the Payment subtab will turn blank. If a payment method is selected, then the Term field will turn blank.

That is because when a Term is selected, the system assumes that the sale will be an Invoice sale. If a Payment Method is selected, the system will assumes that this is a Cash Sale (which doesn't necessarily mean that it will be paid by cash but it will be paid upfront). Therefore, only one field must be filled and the other one must be blank.

To have an Invoice generated from the Sales Order, the payment method will have to be unset from the sales order OR change the form to a Sales Order - Invoice type.

For more details please refer SuiteAnswers - 35604 and 33544

Comment: Really not fair play to jump in when the issue has been solved in comments.

Comment: Yes and no. To me, this provided incremental information that I didn't know. Where the defaults come from and references. The comments until this point provided the what (that it was a cash sale), not the why. (because if there's a payment method it uses that and not terms, even if the customer has terms)

Answer (score 1):

No, the payment method should stay as marked. Is it possible you have scripts or a workflow running that could change this?

You can check by looking at the transaction in the UI, then go to the System -> Notes tab and see which and when fields were changed.

Comment: I just added a comment to the question about with a link showing payment method was set to check and never changed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some transaction re-naming has been done in your account and that is just a normal Cash Sale record with a different name.